# Changing number of columns while using tablesorter pager with ajax

Tags: ajax, tablesorter

I am trying to add/remove columns depending on what is returned from the server in the ajaxProcessing function. I can see in the pager source that this isn't possible directly.

```
                // only add new header text if the length matches
                if ( th && th.length === hl ) {
```

Is there any workaround to this or should I start tinkering with the code? If I need to make changes, any advice on what to start with? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this in the ajaxProcessing event and it did the trick.

```
    var headerCount = $('#id thead tr:eq(0) th').length;
    var hl = data.headers.length;
    if (headerCount < hl) {
        for (var i = headerCount; i < hl; i++) {
            $('#id thead tr:eq(0)').append('<th>' + data.headers[i] + '</th>');
        }
    }else if (headerCount > hl) {
        for (var i = headerCount - 1; i >= hl; i--) {
            $('#id thead tr:eq(0) th:eq(' + i + ')').remove();
        }
    }
    if(headerCount !== hl) $('#id').trigger('updateAll', [false, null]);
```

Comment: You can add that code within the [`ajaxProcessing` callback function](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing); but you shouldn't need to trigger an "updateAll".